# vim: issue with function to compile current buffer

Tags: vim

I have this function to compile my tex files:

```
function! CompileTex()
    silent write!
    call setqflist([])
    echon "compiling with arara ..."
    exec 'lcd %:h'

    if expand("%:p") =~# '\(figuras\|figures\)'
        let mainfile = fnameescape(expand("%:p"))
    else
        let mainfile = fnameescape(Tex_GetMainFileName())
    endif
    let &l:makeprg = 'arara -v ' . mainfile
    silent make!

    if !empty(getqflist())
        copen
        wincmd J
    else
        cclose
        redraw
        echon "successfully compiled"
    endif

endfunction
```

The first conditional is there because when creating figures I want to compile the current buffer even if there is a main file. However when I call the function in a path that contains "figures" I get

```
Error detected while processing function CompileTex:
line 4:
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h": lcd %:h
```

and the `mainfile` variable is set to the main tex file and not to the current buffer as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as the error message suggests, and change "lcd %:h" to "lcd %:p:h".

Also, you don't need the :exec. Just write it directly, it's an ex command:

```
function! CompileTex()
    silent write!
    call setqflist([])
    echon "compiling with arara ..."
    lcd %:p:h
    ...
    etc.
```

Comment: That indeed fixes the error message but the main tex file is still compiled and not the current buffer as I want.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem with my setup. The conditional that checks for "figure" in the path is correct? Or should I modify it?

Comment: That conditional looks right to me. I'm not sure what Tex_GetMainFileName() does, though. Have you verified that function is doing what you want?

Comment: Thanks. Mmm I really don't know what's going on because sometimes the conditional works and sometimes is doesn't. I will investigate further.